# Has anybody from the USA got a tourist visa to Russia recently?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, russia, tourist

Easy process? Hard? Impossible? FWIW, since I'll be in Taipei and then Tokyo over the next month or two, I was planning to try the Russian embassies there.

The [Russian Consul in Phuket](https://phuket.mid.ru/en/) was no help at all.

Comment: Hey Whit and welcome to TravelExchange!
What is your nationality? Russia might not want to give visa's to certain nationalities?

Comment: @JorenVandamme The title would suggest a US Citizen

Comment: That's correct, it suggests. I prefer to be certain to be sure to not have miscommunications.

Comment: Will you be applying as a legal resident of Taiwan or Japan, or will you be in those countries as a visitor/tourist? If the latter, you probably can’t  apply in either location

Comment: @Traveller different countries have different rules, some care about residency, some don't. We should double check what rules are present in the Japanese/Taiwanese consulates.

Comment: @JorenVandamme   I'm USA citizen, been doing the digital nomad life for a few years.

Comment: @Traveller applying as a US resident. Yes, I'm in Taiwan/Japan as a tourist

Comment: @Whit For completeness, what exactly did the response from the Russian consulate in Phuket say? Do you already have a Russian-based sponsor https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/russian-visas/? If so, what have they advised regarding where you may apply? Eg https://japan.interlinkservice.world/en/visa-tourist Do you plan to be in Taiwan / Tokyo long enough for the application process to complete, during which time you’ll be without your passport?

Comment: You describe yourself as a "digital nomad" which suggests that your travel history will look like you're constantly on the move, often treated with suspicion by officials.  Given the political climate I'd suggest rethinking a trip to Russia under a US passport.  Getting in is not the part of the trip to worry about, getting out is.

Comment: I'd be wary of getting [a very, very extended stay visa](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2023/04/08/evan-gershkovich-russia-wsj-journalist-arrested-profile/).

Comment: The Russian consulate will never help a US citizen, think about it. You have to use their visa agency, ILS, to submit for you. Just email or contact them, it's not too hard. The hard part is providing all your financial documents and tax records and criminal history, etc for the background check. Good luck @Whit and enjoy it there, dont listen to the naysayers.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is possible currently for US passport holders to apply for a tourist visa to Russia and it is actually much easier than ever before, at least the past 6+ years I have been applying for them. It is all done through the mail now and requires no interviews anymore which really simplifies things.

Russian consulates ***will not help you at all*** with tourist visas (or any visas for that matter) because Russian consulates are only for Russian citizens. I have learned this the hard way too and its very confusing. You have to submit your visa application to a service company (ILS visa agency) that submits it to the Russian consulate for you. The Russian consulate will never deal with you directly unless you hold Russian citizenship.

My advice is to contact ILS USA, who handles the visa processing for them. You should contact their call center at +1-202-436-4555 or email them `info-newyork@ils-usa.com` to find out your best options  while overseas.

[Their website](https://ils-usa.com/page/65?domain=5&language=10) states they process tourist visas within 4-10 business days. If you are a US passport holder this is your best option that I am aware of.

### Visa Processing

> The Russian Embassy or Consulate General reviews your visa application and decides whether to issue you a visa within a period of 4 to 10 calendar days, after having received all the necessary documents and received payment in full.

> One may not apply for a visa more than six months prior to the intended date of entry into the Russian Federation. Under certain circumstances, this period may be altered at the discretion of the Consulates.

> In extreme emergencies, which require urgent passage to the Russian Federation, the applicant may petition the Consulate to review his materials in an expedited manner, thus reducing the processing time substantially to 3 business days or less. In such situations, the decision to issue an emergency visa is made either by the Russian Ministry of Foreign Affairs, the Federal Migration Service of the Russian Federation, and either the Ambassador or the Consul General of the Russian Federation.

> Likewise, in special circumstances the consulate has the right to review submitted documents for up to 30 days.

They also have a $45 fee for international shipping mentioned in [their mail service instructions](https://ils-usa.com/page/83?domain=5&language=10) which implies you can submit your application from overseas.

ILS will require holding your passport a few days when you send your application, and they advise to call them prior to any lodging of the application. I also know you will not be able to get a visa immediately or overnight unless there is some type of emergency, and it's still at their discretion to allow expedited applications because they have to involve diplomats and bump you to the front of the queue for "special" consideration. I would not advise it unless you absolutely need to.

Currently New York City and Washington DC ILS processing centers are the only centers operating. I am unsure if the Houston office is open or not.

I am no longer eligible for a "tourist" visa to Russia because I married a Russian citizen so I have to get a private visa instead. Our daughter, a US citizen born in the USA, is getting her Russian citizenship currently in Houston. I have had 3 tourist visas to Russia, although I currently do not have one (they have expired). Good luck and do not worry about the Russian consulate, they are usually unpleasant.